# Standard Button is not showing in Lightning

Tags: page-layout

I am not able to see standard button "Sort" on Quote Object / Quote Line Item related List on Lightning.

Only two buttons are visible.

I check the related list property -->button --> all button are checked.

Any one can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

"Sort" button on Quote line item is available in Classic but not yet in Lightning.
Ideas are still open on this topic.

Refer to this related [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CMaAQAW) which is merged into this [one](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YHmBAAW) (and as per newest  comments the feature will be coming soon)